# Can't Install solr on Amazon EC2

Tags: apache, tomcat, amazon-web-services, solr, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install solr on Amazon EC2. However, I can't access the solr url as some people described in their results. For example, [One example](http://blog.grio.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-and-exploit-an-apache-solr-environment-on-amazon-ec2.html) shows once I start solr, then I could access the url with port 8080. However it doesn't happen.

```
 http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8983/solr/admin/
```

Maybe it is because the version has changed. But [another example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-apt-get) shows that  when I installed Tomcat and visit url link below. It still doesn't work.

```
http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080
```

But when I do curl, it does show me content in local.

```
ubuntu@ip-AAA-BB-C-DD:~/solr/solr-5.1.0$ curl "http://localhost:8080"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Apache Tomcat</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>It works !</h1>
```

Now I am really confused that although I have followed the steps, the solr still can't work online!! How can I make it happen? To be more specific, how can I make those links is browsable? such as `http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080` and `http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8983/solr/admin/`

Note: The error message for visiting the url above is that:

```
This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I think this question is more suited for [su]. Your connection attempts are probably blocked by the EC2 firewall.

Comment: @DanielB SO how can I make my question seem by Super User. ANd also if it blocks, what kind of setting I need to edit, possibly?

Comment: @DanielB  I just asked the same questions on Super User. THanks Daniel!

Comment: Check that you have port 8080 - inbound enabled in the security group associated with your EC2 instance. This is available through the EC2 web console.

Comment: @Finbarr I checked my inbound enabled. I did set the http and https for the port. But I am sure whether they are correct. Can you help me judge that? Here is the screenshot -- http://postimg.org/image/cfl9phg4r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a rule in the appropriate security group to enable inbound traffic on port 8080.

```
Type = Custom TCP Rule
Protocol = TCP
Port = 8080
Source Anywhere / 0.0.0.0/0
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! It works! I have one more question, How will port 80 be used? If the default port 80 as https. Similar question to default https port 443.

Comment: Those also need to be in your security group if they are to be accessible externally - like you showed in the image. Depending on your use case it may not be advisable to allow all traffic directly at SOLR. Many times SOLR is accessed by a local script and results published/incorporated into your html output. There are obvious security concerns to watch out for if SOLR is not locked down. eg someone could modify/delete/read your settings, index etc.